Can i use pagination with widget wrap? Flutter
Is there any widget similar to Wrap, which can work with pagination? I tried to use Wrap widget, but it isn't working with pagination. I used bloc as state manager. And there is button which loads another page onTap.
Widget _buildWrap(CategoryLoaded state, BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Wrap(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          spacing: 8,
          runSpacing: 8,
          children: [
            ...(state.categoryModel.results?.map(
                  (categoryModelResult) => _buildPopUpMenuItem(
                      text: categoryModelResult.name ?? '',
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        context.read<ProductsBloc>().add(ProductsFilterEvent(
                            isInitial: true,
                            categoryId: categoryModelResult.id ?? -1));
                      }),
                ) ??
                {}),
          ],
        ),
        if (state.categoryModel.next !=
            null) // if not the last page(pagination)
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: _buildLoadMoreButton(
                  text: 'load more',
                  onTap: () {
                    context
                        .read<CategoryBloc>()
                        .add(CategoryLoadEvent(isInitial: false));
                  }),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }


I tried also use in line of children of widget Wrap
(state.categoryModel.results?.map(
                                    (categoryModelResult) => _buildPopUpMenuItem(
                                        categoryModelResult.name ?? '', () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                      context.read<ProductsBloc>().add(
                                          ProductsFilterEvent(
                                              isInitial: true,
                                              categoryId:
                                                  categoryModelResult.id ?? -1));
                                    }),
                                  ) ??
                                  {})
                              .toList()


What was the problem you were encountering. Can you give me brief?. And I think you should use Expanded or Flexible when using wrap inside column.
